# Laravel - fetch unique rows from table having highest value in x column

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8. Want to fetch from table unique rows (based on name) having highest amount for each name, to be ordered by amount descending.

```
| Name | Amount |
| John |   200  |
| Mane |   100  |
| Zoey |   300  |
| Mane |   300  |
| Zoey |   500  |
```

Result Needed :

```
| Name | Amount |
| Zoey |   500  |
| Mane |   300  |
| John |   200  |
```

Solution in query builder or eloquent both are fine. Please keep in mind that server has ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY rule enforced.

Comment: do you need all the row's fields (select * ) or just Name and Amount in the result ?

Comment: @ml59 table has more fields but i only need those two

Comment: So you should add a `select()` to your query containing the same field in the group by

Answer (score 0):

In your **config => database.php**, make sure mysql strict is false:

```php
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Then you can do something like this:

```php
Post::orderBy('amount', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->pluck('amount', 'name')
```

Results here: https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/c9fdd0e3-3049-4b89-88f4-d905e179953c

Comment: I have updated my answer. You might have to clear the config cache afterward.